# Question about congruence properties of the Dedekind eta function

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Let the modular form of weight $2$ for the group $\Gamma_0(N)$ and for a certain $N$:
\begin{equation}
f(q)= q \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-p^{3n})^2 \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-q^{9n})^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}t_nq^n, \:\: \text{with} \:\:t_1=1. \: 
\end{equation}

Let the elliptic curve $F_3: \: x^3+y^3+z^3=0$.

Then $\#F_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is the number of points on $F_3$ when reduced modulo a prime $p$. Studying $F_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for primes between $2$ and $100$, we see that $t_p=p+1-\#F_3(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is equal to 0.

Is it always true ? Do you know a simple way to demonstrate this ?
I thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: For an elliptic curve with complex multiplication : follow Silverman to express its L-function as an Hecke L-function of quadratic imaginary field, follow Hecke to show it is weight $1$ modular for $\Gamma_0(N)$, find $N$, show your eta product is weight $1$ modular for $\Gamma_0(M)$ with no poles at the cusps, compare $N,M$, compare the first few coefficients, use Sturm bound. There is of course no simple way. The method is the same for all CM elliptic curves so don't choose the curve yourself, follow the examples (in particular $y^2=x^3+x$ and $y^2=x^3\pm x+1$)

Comment: @reuns Nice concise summary. Do you happen to know a reference in English for showing Hecke L-functions are modular? (I was hoping to write a comment not unlike yours, but I've realized I don't know this part of the argument myself!)

Comment: @Wojowu There is Neukrich's ANT doing the whole proof, personally I know the key ingredients but I get stuck at making it clear and readable because we need to show modularity not only for $z\to -1/Nz$ but for the whole $\Gamma_0(N)$, thus to consider the twists $\sum_{a \in \Bbb{Z}^2} e^{2i \pi z (\|M(a+c/N)\|^2 } e^{2i \pi b^\top a/N}$ (where $M$ is the matrix of the quadratic form corresponding to an ideal class, the character is cut in pieces hidden in it and $c,b$) and show $z\to-1/z,z\to z+d/N$ permute them. That's why proving Weil converse theorem in full generality is useful.

Comment: @reuns Thanks, but I'm afraid I cannot find anything relevant to this topic in Neukirch's book, are you sure this is the right book you are thinking of?

Comment: @Wojowu p.490 Neukrich proves the functional equation and level of all twists by Dirichlet characters, summing over those of good $N$ we get $f(z+d/N)$ for all $d$ and that $z \mapsto z+1/N,z \mapsto -1/Nz$ permute the $f(z+d/N)$ which means $f$ is invariant for a finite index subgroup of $\Gamma_0(N)$, and the way they are permuted means this group is $\Gamma_0(N)$.